# How to get my backup and restore working using FOSS tools

Tags: boot, backup

I'm a hobbyist with a short budget, a focus on FOSS tools, and 8 Linux systems.  I've been backing up stuff for years on a collection of ever-larger external drives.  This started about 15years ago.  I mostly use tar and ntfsclone, but I'm expecting to switch over to dar instead of tar.

But this question is about the backups I've been taking all along.  I have one old laptop I'm about to donate to a non-profit I volunteer with and I wanted to see if I could actually restore the system from one of my backups.  So far, I cannot.  It all seems well until the reboot, trying to bring up the old xenial xubuntu system that I had backed up.

Grub is fine.  The initial fsck seems to be fine.  But then the screen stays dark for a long time until I get a "Welcome to emergency mode!" message.  Following instructions, I listed the relevant boot logs with "journalctl -xb".  I even captured them on a thumb drive.  But there's over 2000 lines of log and I have no idea what I'm looking for.  It seems to be full of reports of things going normally, and I didn't notice anything to indicate why it wound up in emergency mode.

I did treat /dev /proc and /sys specially, restoring a bind mound of /dev and leaving /proc and /sys empty.  My tar backups omitted the usual cache and tmp directories.

I have the original drive, unmolested, and I'm attempting to do the restore to a fresh drive in the original laptop.  So I can change stuff and try again.

I'm hoping for a hint about what to look for in the logs, or hints about what else needs special attention.

Comment: How did you make the backup, and what does it contain? Was the system powered on when you made it?

Comment: I use tar for Linux filesystems, and dd or ntfsclone for Windows/DOS filesystems.  I'm running the system when I back it up.

Comment: That's probably the problem. The system should be off when you make a system image.

Comment: I have my doubts.  This is not an "image" in the usual sense.  It's a tarball of the file system.  I expected that it would be the equivalent of what I get if the power fails and I restart.  Perhaps some lock files and such to deal with but not complete failure to re-launch.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of the difference until now. Seems you know more about this than I do.